# How to ignore invalid byte sequences when doing a pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I need a way to just ignore all invalid characters when doing dumps.

I get over a thousand tables from hundreds of sources on a regular basis and much of it is of questionable quality. The way I am getting data into the database sidesteps any incorrect or invalid encoding. I have no need to repair any of them.

But when I am backing up my database pg_dump chokes on every one of them. It seemed like this was not a problem before I moved to version 9.6.

I have three choices. Go fix each table when it chokes. Run a process to strip all non-ascii stuff from every field in every table. Both take time and add a step to my backup procedure.

Or I can find a switch that just tells pg_dump to stop being so picky. Any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "The way I am getting data into the database sidesteps any incorrect or invalid encoding"? Can you roll up a short example?

Comment: try creating a db with same encoding as source one and restore dump to it, then make a dump that will fit your needed encoding

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL tries to be 100% exact about encoding, and the checks have become tighter from version to version. That may explain what you observe.

PostgreSQL has no switch for `pg_dump` to disable encoding check.

If you don't care about encoding, you should use the database encoding `SQL_ASCII`, but that still won't allow zero bytes in strings (if you have got that).

You could use a physical backup with `pg_basebackup` which will solve your immediate problem, but expect more trouble along the road.